# SomeService UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

i have this code from a tutorial:

```
// Do the search and show the results in tableview
// Deactivate the UISearchBar

// You'll probably want to do this on another thread
// SomeService is just a dummy class representing some 
// api that you are using to do the search
NSArray *results = [SomeService doSearch:searchBar.text];
```

what is the SomeService and how to download it?

(i searched at google.)

Comment: look Omar abdelhafith's answer. he says that there are not class like `SomeService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a demo class, you will not be able to find it online, you must refer to the same class tutorial to get this class

As the comment says

> is just a dummy class representing some

So there is no class that you will find called `SomeService`

Comment: OK. you know class for search?

Comment: this is search with UISearchBar. i want to search at tableview's mountable data.